# Accumulating totals for a dictionary value in Python

Tags: python

Hey all I could use a bit of help. I'm trying to write a program in Python that takes certain elements from a csv file in my case element[10], element[11], and element[15] and outputs a nice dictionary. What I am trying to do is add the numbers from elements [11] and [15] and use it for the value part of the dictionary and have element[10] be the key. The problem I'm running into is I want the elements [11] and [15] added to the previous totals every time the key is found. For example key Alaska is found 53 times and should total 1,198,047. I know my if statement is wrong I just can't figure out how. Here is the code I have so far

```
def main():
    inreport = open("state_crime - CS152.csv", "r")
    report = inreport.readlines()
    statedict = {}
    total = 0

    for lines in report[1:]:
        values = lines.split(',')
        totalcrime = int(values[11]) + int(values[15])
        state = values[10]
        statedict[state] = totalcrime
        if state in statedict:
            statedict[state] = total + totalcrime


    for akey in statedict.keys():
        print (akey," "*(20-len(akey)), (f"{statedict[akey]:,}").rjust(10))
    


    inreport.close()

main()
```

Comment: Please share a part of csv and expected output.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/D2xSiHJz expected output would be Alaska 1,198,047

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful for you to go through a few rows of your csv file to see what the code would do.

In this case, "total" is not a useful variable the way you set it up, because it always remains 0.

Also, the line "statedict[state] = totalcrime" is unhelpful. Let's say that in row 2, Alaska has a totalcrime of 500. Then statedict['Alaska'] would be set to 500. Then, let's say row 5 is also for Alaska, and has a totalcrime of 300. This line would get rid of the previous value, and set statedict['Alaska'] to 300.

You can try replacing this section

```
statedict[state] = totalcrime
if state in statedict:
    statedict[state] = total + totalcrime
```

with the following:

```
if state in statedict:
    statedict[state] = statedict[state] + totalcrime  #if the state is already in the keys, adds totalcrime to the existing value
else:
    statedict[state] = totalcrime       #if the state isn't already in the dictionary, creates a new key for it with totalcrime as the value
```

Comment: No problem. Fyi, this question will continue to show up as unanswered unless you accept an answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable called 'total' wich is always 0. You should get rid of it.
Your code does not cumulate each state totalcrime since you assign the last read value in it through `statedict[state] = total + totalcrime`

Here is a solution :

```
totalcrime = int(values[11]) + int(values[15])
state = values[10]
if state in statedict:
    statedict[state] += totalcrime
else:
    statedict[state] = totalcrime
```

The goal is to tell python to add the value if it is already in statedict dict or just create the state key with first total crime value if not.